# Datepicker as dialog

Tags: android, datepicker

I have to write a date picker in a fragment.
On clicking the edit text(which is non-editable) date-picker has to be launched as a dialog.
I want to do it without writing any custom date-picker class,by simply launching the default date-picker on clicking the edit text.
The selected date should be displayed in the edit text.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO full of such examples

Comment: here is the android doc not custom one what you need http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html why don't want to use dialogfragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
dpd.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-

```
`Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new     
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    updateLabel();
}

};

edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});

  private void updateLabel() {

String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Create *DatePickerFragment*:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        //do stuff

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

and by clicking the editText (setting it to focusable=false) call the following method:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Comment: Hi..thnx for the reply..I couldn't get the date picker picker pop-up